# How to run repo android on CentOS?

Tags: android, git, centos, android-source, repo

I try to run repo with `repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest` command after I have installed the repo on my CentOS. But, the error occurs like this

```
File "/root/bin/repo", line 603, in 
 main(sys.argv[1:])
 File "/root/bin/repo", line 570, in main
_Init(args)
File "/root/bin/repo", line 184, in _Init
_CheckGitVersion()
File "/root/bin/repo", line 213, in _CheckGitVersion
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
File "/usr/lib/python2.4/subprocess.py", line 550, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.4/subprocess.py", line 996, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try compiling and reinstalling git from, the command should be `git` not `repo`

```
yum -y install zlib-devel openssl-devel perl cpio expat-devel gettext-devel autoconf curl curl-devel gcc
ldconfig

wget  http://www.codemonkey.org.uk/projects/git-snapshots/git/git-latest.tar.gz
tar zxvf git-latest.tar.gz
cd git-<date>
make configure
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
make install
```

After it is installed, run `git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest`.

I have just done the clone successfully:

```
xxx@xxx:~/temp$ git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
Cloning into manifest...
remote: Counting objects: 261, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (47/47)
remote: Total 261 (delta 41), reused 261 (delta 41)
Receiving objects: 100% (261/261), 117.65 KiB | 56 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (41/41), done.

xxx@xxx:~/temp/manifest$ git remote -v
origin  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest (fetch)
origin  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest (push)
```